Energy of a flowing fluid
A pump transfers mechanical energy to a fluid by raising its pressure. The pressure of a flowing fluid is associated with its mechanical energy.
$\mathrm{Pa}=\mathrm{N}/\mathrm{m}^2=\mathrm{N}.\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{m}^3=\mathrm{J}/\mathrm{m}^3$ Energy per unit volume and $\mathrm{P}/\rho$ has unit $\mathrm{J}/\mathrm{kg}$ which is energy per unit mass.
The book (Thermodynamics:An engineering approach by Boles and Çengel) I am studying from states that pressure is not energy but a force acting on a fluid through a distance to produce work. Flow work can be viewed as part of the energy of a flowing fluid.
If we consider the system as the fluid element shown, the fluid element has stored forms of energy which are the kinetic and potential energies as well as the microscopic forms of energy (internal energy). Since transporting a fluid from one to another does not involve the conversion of thermal, chemical, or nuclear forms of energy into mechanical energy, the only forms of energy contained within the system would be kinetic and potential energy.
Shouldn't the net force acting on the fluid element by the surrounding fluid, as it is pushed through a distance $\mathrm{d}x$, be equal to the changes in the kinetic and potential energies of the fluid element. Why is flow work, which is a dynamic form of energy, not contained within the system but is realized at the system boundary, where it is transferred to the the system from the surrounding forces and manifests itself as an increase or decrease in kinetic a part of the flowing fluid ?

Pressure is no more $J/m^3$ then $kg/(m\cdot sec^2)$ or any other equivalent expression indirectly related to an energy measure. Never think of pressure as energy per unit volume, think of pressure as force per unit area. Work is what you measure at the perimeter or boundary, and energy, or rather change in energy, is what you think that work represents within the boundary.


Shouldn't the net force acting on the fluid element by the surrounding fluid, as it is pushed through a distance $dx$, be equal to the changes in the kinetic and potential energies of the fluid element.

Yes, it is, provided the fluid is incompressible.

Why is flow work, which is a dynamic form of energy, not contained within the system but is realized at the system boundary, where it is transferred to the the system from the surrounding forces and manifests itself as an increase or decrease in kinetic a part of the flowing fluid ?

Flow work is not a form of energy. It is a term in the Bernoulli equation, a work of pressure forces on one end of a fluid column in a streamtube.
Let's start with what pressure is, and is not.
Pressure of a fluid $p$ is not directly part of net energy density of the fluid. It has the same units as energy density, but conceptually, pressure is a force per unit area, and its increase is not necessarily associated with any increase of energy in the fluid.
For example, in water at rest, which is almost incompressible, you can cause substantial increase in pressure (e.g. by a factor of 2), with only a very small decrease of its volume $V$, thus $pV$ increases almost by a factor of 2. But since the piston moves only very little, only very small work is done to accomplish this, many times smaller than $pV$. This is possible because $pV$ is not part of the fluid energy in the physics sense.
The Bernoulli equation is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 + \rho g h + p = const.
$$
and it holds only for incompressible flow streamlines (if the fluid element compresses, it does not hold).
We can rewrite this equation, by multiplying both sides with volume of a small fluid element $V$, (we denote $\rho V = m$):
$$
\frac{1}{2} m v^2 + mg h + p V = const.
$$
"Flow work" is a term used for the product $pV$. It is work of pressure force on one end of the fluid column, as the column shifts in its streamtube, to discharge fluid of volume $V$. But there is also the other end, so it is not the total work on the fluid column.
Thus, the term is connected to work of pressure forces on the fluid streamtube.
When we take "flow works" $pV$ of an incompressible fluid element at both endpoints of a streamtube, and subtract them, we get net work done on the streamtube by pressure forces of the surrounding fluid in a process where the streamtube fluid shifts a little and discharges fluid of volume $V$ on one end:
$$
W = p_1 V - p_2V.
$$
This difference of "flow works" is net work of all the pressure forces on the fluid column.
To illustrate this is true, we can use a special kind of work-energy theorem: work of pressure forces on the fluid flowing in a streamtube equals change of kinetic + potential energy of that fluid to derive the Bernoulli equation.
Energy of the fluid column (of variable cross-section and shape) coming through the streamtube is sum of kinetic and potential energy:
$$
E_{column} = \int_{column} \frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 + \rho g h~dV.
$$
When the fluid column displaces a little so that the streamtube discharges fluid of volume $V$, the column changes its shape on both ends; it loses an element with energy $(\frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2 + \rho gh_1)V$ in the rear, and acquires an element with energy $(\frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2 + \rho gh_2)V$ in the front. So change of energy of the fluid column is
$$
\Delta E_{column} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2  + mgh_2 - \frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2 - mgh_1\right) V.
$$
The work-energy theorem $W = \Delta E$ then implies
$$
(p_1-p_2)V = \frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2  + mgh_2 - \frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2 - mgh_1.
$$
Dividing by the factor $V$, we get the Bernoulli equation.

I hope you can find the answer to all your questions in the balance of kinetic energy.
Differential form. The differential form of this equation is derived from the scalar product of the momentum balance equation with the velocity field,
$$\begin{aligned}
0 & = \mathbf{u} \cdot \left[ \rho\frac{D \mathbf{u}}{Dt} - \nabla \cdot \mathbb{T} - \rho \mathbf{g} \right] = \\
& = \rho \frac{D }{Dt} \frac{|\mathbf{u}|^2}{2} - \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \cdot \mathbb{T} - \rho \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{g} = \\
& = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \rho \frac{|\mathbf{u}|^2}{2}  \right) + \nabla \cdot \left( \rho \frac{|\mathbf{u}|^2}{2} \mathbf{u} \right)- \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \cdot \mathbb{T} - \rho \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{g} \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
having relied on the continuity equation for the density to derive the conservative form from the convective form. Here $\mathbb{T}$ is the stress tensor, that for a viscous Newtonian fluid can be split as the sum of pressure stress and viscous stress,
$$\mathbb{T} = -p \mathbb{I} + \mathbb{S} = -p \mathbb{I} + 2 \mu \mathbb{D} + \lambda (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) \mathbb{I} \ ,$$
being $\mathbb{D} = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \nabla \mathbf{u} + \nabla^T \mathbf{u} \right]$ the velocity deformation tensor.
Integral form. Integrating over a control volume $V$ the integral balance reads
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dt} \int_{V} \rho k + \oint_V \rho k \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} & = \int_V \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{u} +  \int_V \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \cdot \mathbb{T} = \\
& =  \int_V \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{u} +  \oint_{\partial V} \underbrace{\mathbf{\mathbf{\hat{n}}} \cdot \mathbb{T}}_{\mathbf{t}_n} \cdot \mathbf{u} - \int_V \mathbb{T} : \nabla \mathbb{u} \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
having used integration by parts and Cauchy relation linking the stress vector $\mathbf{t}_n$ acting on a surface with its normal vector $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ through the stress tensor $\mathbb{T}$. For Newtonian fluids, the last integral can be recast as
$$\int_{V} p \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} - \int_{V} \left[ 2 \mu |\mathbb{D}|^2 + \lambda (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u})^2 \right] \ ,$$
and it can be interpreted as the power of internal stress: the first term is the power of pressure stress, while the latter is the power of viscosity stress (it's viscous dissipation as it's non-positive). Thus, the balance of kinetic energy can be recast and interpreted as
$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{V} \rho k = - \oint_V \rho k \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} + \int_V \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot \mathbf{u} +  \oint_{\partial V} \mathbf{t}_n \cdot \mathbf{u} + \int_{V} p \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} - \int_{V} \left[ 2 \mu |\mathbb{D}|^2 + \lambda (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u})^2 \right]$$
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d K_V}{dt} & = -\Phi_{\partial V}(\rho k) + P^{ext}_V + P^{ext}_{\partial V} + P^{int} \\
& = -\Phi_{\partial V}(\rho k) + P^{tot} \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
i.e. the time derivative of the kinetic energy of a system equals the total power acting on the system (and this is exactly the theorem of kinetic energy for closed systems) and the flux of kinetic energy through its boundary (non zero, if the system is not closed but it can exchange mass with the external environment).
